# Нужно сделать двумерный массив и упорядочить строки таблицы в порядке возрастания количества положительных элементов в каждой строке

Tags: c, массивы

Я сделал массив но никак не выходит посчитать кол-во натуральных элементов, если ставить условия в for то матрица ломается.

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() 
{
int S, C, sn, cn, k=0, temp, j=0;;
    
printf("Type the number of strings: ");
scanf("%u", &sn);

if (sn < 1) 
{
    puts("The number of strings should be greater then 0.");
    return -1;
}

printf("Type the number of columns: ");
scanf("%u", &cn);

if (cn < 1) 
{
    puts("The number of columns should be greater then 0.");
    return -1;
}
float X[sn][cn];
for ( C = 1; C < (cn+1); C ++ ) 
    for ( S = 1; S < (sn+1); S ++ ) 
 scanf ("%d", & X[S][C]);
  while (k<cn){
if (X[k][j]>0){k=k+1;temp=temp+1;
}
if (k=S){
printf("ct=%d\n", temp);
temp=0;
j=j+1;}}
return 0;}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Массивы нумеруются с нуля. Обходить лучше по строкам, сразу же можно и записывать количество положительных элементов.

```
float X[sn][cn];
float NumPlus[sn] = {0};
for ( S = 0; S < sn; S++ ) 
    for ( C = 0; C < cn; C++ ) {
      scanf ("%d", & X[S][C]);
      if (X[S][C] > 0)
         NumPlus[S]++;    
    }
for ( S = 0; S < sn; S++ )
   printf("ct[%d]=%d", S, ct[S]);
```

Затем выполняете любую сортировку, для сравнения используя значения из NumPlus. Когда обмениваете строки, заодно обменивайте и соответствующие значения из NumPlus.

Comment: а не подскажите как для каждой строки был отдельный счетчик чтобы их потом менять код я поменял но считывает только общее кол-во положительных элементов

Comment: ```
int main() 
{
int S, C, sn, cn, j=0,k =0;;
    
printf("Type the number of strings: ");
scanf("%u", &sn);

if (sn < 1) 
{
    puts("The number of strings should be greater then 0.");
    return -1;
}

printf("Type the number of columns: ");
scanf("%u", &cn);

if (cn < 1) 
{
    puts("The number of columns should be greater then 0.");
    return -1;
}
float X[sn][cn];
ct[sn]={0};
for ( C = 1; C < (cn+1); C ++ ) 
 for ( S = 1; S < (sn+1); S ++ ){
 scanf ("%d", & X[S][C]);
 if (X[S][C] > 0) 
 ct[S]=ct+1; 
 }
printf("ct=%d", ct);
return 0;}```

Comment: Так NumPlus[sn] - это и есть отдельные счетчики для каждой строки. Зачем вы изменили на непонятное `ct[S]=ct+1`?

Comment: я изменил полностью и убрал в итоге после переменной [S] и [sn] потому что компилятор вообще не работает с ними и выводит кол-во положительных во всей матрице

Comment: Про то, что массивы индексируются с нуля, а не с единицы, вы так и не осознали?  `потому что компилятор вообще не работает с ними`  да ну? Я добавил вывод.

Comment: @Dietyh Помогло?